# Repositioning CSS slide out effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the feedback form slide out from the bottom of the image which is contained within a div, but after a day trying all sorts of positioning I have been learning on the web, I cannot get it to behave right, though I have managed to get it in the picbox div at one stage, but it affected the behaviour. I have reset the code to the beginning.

I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, but a few pointers wouldn't go amiss, like where to start! Should I be using floats? I realise the relative positioning uses the whole window, so I guess this should go too. Any help / Guidance is hugely appreciated.

Here is the CSS code:

```
    #picbox
      {
    width:560px;
    background-color:#363;
    color: #9C9;
    border:1px solid #030;  
            margin:0 auto;  
     }    

    #slideout {
        position: fixed;
        top: 40px;
        left: 0;
        width: 35px;
        padding: 12px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background: #6DAD53;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    }
    #slideout_inner {
        position: fixed;
        top: 40px;
        left: -250px;
        background: #6DAD53;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 25px;
        height: 130px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        text-align: left;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    }
    #slideout_inner textarea {
        width: 190px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    #slideout:hover {
        left: 250px;
    }
    #slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
        left: 0;
    }
```

And the HTML

```
    <div id="picbox">

        <img src="http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/classifieds/2013/05/26/314873/wanted-yorkshire-terrier-puppy-female-51a22e8faaace.jpg">
    </div>

     <div id="slideout">
    <img src="feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post feedback"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/treetops/9386jwoe/6/)

Comment: Can you explain little bit more what do you want ?

Where you want to see the feedback form ? @Treetops

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I want the green feedback image/tab to be positioned at the foot of the dog photo, and when hovered over, the feedback form to then slide out from the bottom of the dog photo. So basically I want the whole thing to work how it does now, but be repositioned from the left of the page, to the bottom of the image and slide out horizontally down. I hope that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Carefully look at the position style

```
#picbox
    {
        width:560px;
        background-color:#363;
        color: #9C9;
        border:1px solid #030;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    }

#slideout {
            position: relative;  /* Carefully Look at this style what I did here */
            top: 40px;
            left: -250px;  /* Carefully Look at this style what I did here */
            width: 35px;
            padding: 12px 0;
            text-align: center;
            background: #6DAD53;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
            border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        }
        #slideout_inner { /*the hidden form slideout */
            position: relative;  /* Carefully Look at this style what I did here */
            background: #6DAD53;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 25px;
            height: 130px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
        }
        #slideout_inner textarea {
            width: 190px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 6px;
        }

        #slideout:hover { /* the feedback hover */
            left: 0;  /* Carefully Look at this style what I did here */
        }
        #slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
            left: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, not quite the position I was looking to achieve. Please look under the dog photo on this new fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/treetops/9386jwoe/8/

Comment: you can see the red text is where I was hoping to position the slide-out feedback form, so it looks like it is sliding out from behind the image, but sliding down vertically. (apologies for my mistakes earlier)